# Closed queries re-open when connecting to DB using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbench latest version (6.3) I've set up an Amazon EC2 connection successfully. Every time I open the connection, I've noticed all queries I did before are being opened, even if I closed them using right click -> "Close All" option. These queries have dynamic names like `{0303FFF4-FB6D-4EF3-A9EC-2...`

I don't want these queries to remain stored, as most of the time they're just temporary queries I need for some quick data gathering.

Can somebody please help me with these? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was some kind of auto-save feature from Amazon EC2 instance or some kind of bug, but nope my bad.
I found [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73487) and at the bottom of the page this is the answer:

> Andres Giordano:
>   This is not a bug!!! You have to go to Edit --> Preferences --> General --> SQL Editor (panel) and uncheck "Save snapshot of open editor...."

That's the correct answer. Once this option is disabled, no more queries are stored and re open.
I hope this tip is useful for somebody. Greetings!